# Integration via trapezoidal sums in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, sum, numerical-integration

I need help finding an integral of a function using trapezoidal sums.

The program should take successive trapezoidal sums with `n = 1, 2, 3, ...`
subintervals until there are two neighouring values of `n` that differ by less than a given tolerance. I want at least one `FOR` loop within a `WHILE` loop and I don't want to use the trapz function. The program takes four inputs:

- `f`: A function handle for a function of `x`.
- `a`: A real number.
- `b`: A real number larger than `a`.
- `tolerance`: A real number that is positive and very small

The problem I have is trying to implement the formula for trapezoidal sums which is
`Δx/2[y0 + 2y1 + 2y2 + … + 2yn-1 + yn]`

Here is my code, and the area I'm stuck in is the "sum" part within the `FOR` loop. I'm trying to sum up `2y2 + 2y3....2yn-1` since I already accounted for `2y1`.  I get an answer, but it isn't as accurate as it should be. For example, I get `6.071717974723753` instead of `6.101605982576467`.

Thanks for any help!

```
function t=trapintegral(f,a,b,tol)
format compact; format long;
syms x;
oldtrap = ((b-a)/2)*(f(a)+f(b));
n = 2;
h = (b-a)/n;
newtrap = (h/2)*(f(a)+(2*f(a+h))+f(b));
while (abs(newtrap-oldtrap)>=tol)
    oldtrap = newtrap;
    for i=[3:n]
        dx = (b-a)/n;
        trapezoidsum = (dx/2)*(f(x) + (2*sum(f(a+(3:n-1))))+f(b));
        newtrap = trapezoidsum;
    end
end
t = newtrap;
end
```

Comment: "after every n subintervals more trapezoids are created" - it's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: after every n subintervals the number of trapezoids under the curve increase

Comment: Trapezoidal integration is included in core Matlab, see `trapz`, and if you are interested in how it is implemented, look at the source: `edit trapz`. Btw., loops should be avoided when programming Matlab as far as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this code isn't working is because there are two slight errors in your summation for the trapezoidal rule.  What I am precisely referring to is this statement:

```
trapezoidsum = (dx/2)*(f(x) + (2*sum(f(a+(3:n-1))))+f(b));
```

Recall the equation for the trapezoidal integration rule:

[image]
[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)</sup>

For the first error, `f(x)` should be `f(a)` as you are including the starting point, and shouldn't be left as symbolic.  In fact, you should simply get rid of the `syms x` statement as it is not useful in your script.  `a` corresponds to `x1` by consulting the above equation.

The next error is the second term.  You actually need to multiply your index values `(3:n-1)` by `dx`.  Also, this should actually go from `(1:n-1)` and I'll explain later.  The equation above goes from 2 to `N`, but for our purposes, we are going to go from 1 to `N-1` as you have your code set up like that.

Remember, in the trapezoidal rule, you are subdividing the finite interval into `n` pieces.  The i<sup>th</sup> piece is defined as:

```
x_i = a + dx*i;  ,
```

where `i` goes from `1` up to `N-1`.  Note that this starts at **1** and not 3.  The reason why is because the first piece is already taken into account by `f(a)`, and we only count up to `N-1` as piece `N` is accounted by `f(b)`.  For the equation, this goes from 2 to `N` and by modifying the code this way, this is precisely what we are doing in the end.

Therefore, your statement actually needs to be:

```
trapezoidsum = (dx/2)*(f(a) + (2*sum(f(a+dx*(1:n-1))))+f(b));
```

Try this and let me know if you get the right answer.  FWIW, MATLAB already implements trapezoidal integration by doing [`trapz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) as @ADonda already pointed out.  However, you need to properly structure what your `x` and `y` values are before you set this up.  In other words, you would need to set up your `dx` before hand, then calculate your `x` points using the `x_i` equation that I specified above, then use these to generate your `y` values.  You then use `trapz` to calculate the area.  In other words:

```
dx = (b-a) / n;
x = a + dx*(0:n);
y = f(x);
trapezoidsum = trapz(x,y);
```

You can use the above code as a reference to see if you are implementing the trapezoidal rule correctly.  Your implementation and using the above code should generate the same results.  All you have to do is change the value of `n`, then run this code to generate the approximation of the area for different subdivisions underneath your curve.

---

## Edit - August 17th, 2014

I figured out why your code isn't working.  Here are the reasons why:

1. The `for` loop is unnecessary.  Take a look at the `for` loop iteration.  You have a loop going from `i = [3:n]` yet you **don't** reference the `i` variable at all in your loop.  As such, you don't need this at all.
2. You are not computing successive intervals properly.  What you need to do is when you compute the trapezoidal sum for the `n`th subinterval, you then **increment** this value of `n`, then compute the trapezoidal rule again.  This value is not being incremented properly in your `while` loop, which is why your area is never improving.
3. You need to save the previous area inside the `while` loop, then when you compute the next area, that's when you determine whether or not the difference between the areas is less than the tolerance.  We can also get rid of that code at the beginning that tries and compute the area for `n = 2`.  That's not needed, as we can place this inside your `while` loop.  As such, this is what your code should look like:

---

```
function t=trapintegral(f,a,b,tol)
format long; %// Got rid of format compact. Useless
%// n starts at 2 - Also removed syms x - Useless statement
n = 2;
newtrap = ((b-a)/2)*(f(a) + f(b)); %// Initialize
oldtrap = 0; %// Initialize to 0
while (abs(newtrap-oldtrap)>=tol)
    oldtrap = newtrap; %//Save the old area from the previous iteration
    dx = (b-a)/n; %//Compute width
    %//Determine sum
    trapezoidsum = (dx/2)*(f(a) + (2*sum(f(a+dx*(1:n-1))))+f(b));
    newtrap = trapezoidsum; % //This is the new sum
    n = n + 1; % //Go to the next value of n
end
t = newtrap;
end
```

By running your code, this is what I get:

```
trapezoidsum = trapintegral(@(x) (x+x.^2).^(1/3),1,4,0.00001)

trapezoidsum = 

6.111776299189033
```

## Caveat

Look at the way I defined your function.  You **must** use element-by-element operations as the `sum` command inside the loop will be vectorized.  Take a look at the `^` operations specifically.  You need to prepend a dot to the operations.  Once you do this, I get the right answer.

## Edit #2 - August 18th, 2014

You said you want at least one `for` loop.  This is highly inefficient, and whoever specified having one `for` loop in the code really doesn't know how MATLAB works.  Nevertheless, you can use the `for` loop to accumulate the `sum` term.  As such:

```
function t=trapintegral(f,a,b,tol)
format long; %// Got rid of format compact. Useless
%// n starts at 3 - Also removed syms x - Useless statement
n = 3;
%// Compute for n = 2 first, then proceed if we don't get a better
%// difference tolerance
newtrap = ((b-a)/2)*(f(a) + f(b)); %// Initialize
oldtrap = 0; %// Initialize to 0
while (abs(newtrap-oldtrap)>=tol)
    oldtrap = newtrap; %//Save the old area from the previous iteration
    dx = (b-a)/n; %//Compute width
    %//Determine sum
    %// Initialize
    trapezoidsum = (dx/2)*(f(a) + f(b));

    %// Accumulate sum terms
    %// Note that we multiply each term by (dx/2), but because of the
    %// factor of 2 for each of these terms, these cancel and we thus have dx
    for n2 = 1 : n-1
        trapezoidsum = trapezoidsum + dx*f(a + dx*n2);
    end
    newtrap = trapezoidsum; % //This is the new sum
    n = n + 1; % //Go to the next value of n
end
t = newtrap;
end
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I'm trying to write the code without using trapz so I used your first suggestion but the answer isn't as close as it should be. For example trapintegral(@(x) (x+x^2)^(1/3),1,4,0.00001) should yield 6.111776299189035
but I get 6.071717974723753 instead. I fiddled around with it some more but I can't get my answer to change

Comment: @BruceWayne I figured it out.  You wrote your `loop` wrong.  You're not comparing successive `n` subintervals properly.  I'll make an answer soon.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out the loop problem. But I need at least 1 FOR Loop in the while loop. I understand the code you wrote but I'm having trouble implementing back in somewhere that for loop. Thanks though for the help so far! :)

Comment: @BruceWayne - Why do you need at least one `for` loop?  That is highly inefficient.  I'll modify the code, but I highly advise against the `for` loop.

Comment: I know and I'm sorry about that but it's just something I want my code to include. Again though, thanks so much for your input so far.

Comment: @BruceWayne not a problem. I've edited my answer with this for loop addition. Let me know if that works. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Your code wasn't as accurate for only one scenario which I solved by replacing realmax with ((b-a)/2)*(f(a)+f(b)). Setting the initial newtrap to this made the program work every time. So again, thank you for all your time, effort, and input! It was greatly appreciated!

Comment: @BruceWayne - No worries.  I'll change this in my code.  Glad it helped!