# Matlab trapezoidal Rule

Tags: function, matlab, numerical-integration

[image]

I created a fas.m script, but I'm getting wrong result.

**FUNCTION**

```
 function [fnc2] = fas(x)
if x>=0 && x<1
fnc2 = x^3;
elseif x>=1 && x<2
        fnc2 = 2-((x^2)/5);
elseif x>2
            fnc2 = x^2+x;
 elseif x<0 
     fprintf('x is smaller than 0, function is not defined');

end
```

**TRAPEZOIDAL RULE SUM**

```
clear
clc
h=0.05;
x=0.05;
x0=0;
xn=3;
while x<=2.95
fas(x);
I=0.025*(fas(x0)+2*fas(x)+fas(x0));
x=x+h;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trapezoidal rule is,

[image]

so,

```
h = 0.05;
x = 0;
I = 0;
while x < 3
   I = I + h * (fas(x) + fas(x + h)) / 2;
   x = x + h;
end
disp(I);
```

you will get `I = 11.3664` while the actual value of `I` is `10.3667`.

Comment: Or vectorized: `x = 0 :h: 3;
f = fas(x);
I = sum(h * (f(1 : end - 1) + f(2 : end)) / 2);`

Comment: @Kamtal - Also take a look at this post for insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342462/integration-via-trapezoidal-sums-in-matlab/25345406#25345406 .  This code keeps calculating the trapezoidal rule by increasing the number of trapezoids required to estimate the area until the relative error is less than a certain amount.  Either way, very good in fixing the OP's answer.